Почему не получается подключиться к сокету?
server.rs:
fn main() {
    println!("{}, version {}", env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"), env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"));

    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
    
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();
        println!("listening... ");
        handle_connection(stream);
    }

}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream){
    let mut buffer = [0; 512];
    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]));
    stream.write(b"success");   
}

client.rs:
fn main(){
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
    println!("connecting...");
    stream.write(b"success").unwrap();

}

В таком виде все работает, однако когда я меняю локалхост на свой внешний ip, соединение не устанавливается.

А вы уверены, что внешний ip действительно «свой»? Вы проверяли, что ваш интернет-провайдер предоставляет услугу перенаправления запросов с внешнего ip на ваше конкретное устройство?

@andreymal Ого, а как проверить?

скорее всего проблема решиться, если сделать
let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8080").unwrap();
